# How do I make react re-render if the access/refresh token was changed during the interception of an axios response and not through state?

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I would like for my useEffect to run because it handles updating the current user, and uses that value to display authenticated views, authenticated components (ie authenticated navbar), and more. However, my useEffect does not run because react does not monitor changes to the local storage, and I am unable to call the state updater in my interceptor because it is not a react component (ie: `setAccessToken(null)`). Is there another way to do this?

Here is my interceptor:

```
instance.interceptors.response.use(
    (res) => {
        return res;
    },
    async (err) => {
        const originalConfig = err.config;
        
        if (err?.response?.data?.code === "token_not_valid" && err?.response) {
            // expired access token
            if (err.response.status === 403 && !originalConfig._retry) {
                originalConfig._retry = true;

                try {
                    const resp = await instance.post("/token/refresh/", {
                        refresh: TokenService.getLocalRefreshToken(),
                    });

                    const { access } = resp.data;
                    console.log(" ~ file: api.tsx:79 ~ access:", access);
                    TokenService.updateLocalAccessToken(access);

                    return instance(originalConfig);
                } catch (_error) {
                    return Promise.reject(_error);
                }
            }

            // expired refresh token
            if (err.response.status === 401 && !originalConfig._retry) {
                localStorage.removeItem("access");
                localStorage.removeItem("refresh")
            }
        }
        return Promise.reject(err);
    },
);
```

This correctly remakes the request given a valid refresh token, and it will clear both tokens if the refresh token is invalid.

Here is a small snippet of my AuthProvider:

```
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState(
        TokenService.getLocalAccessToken(),
    );
    const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState(
        TokenService.getLocalRefreshToken(),
    );

   // ...

   useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchUser() {
            if (accessToken) {
                // fetch current user
            } else {
                // remove user
            }
        }
        fetchUser();
    }, [accessToken, refreshToken]);

   //...
}
```

Thank you in advance for sharing your knowledge and insights with me!

Comment: In your case, the refreshToken is only getting called when the component loads since that is used to set the initial state.  So refreshToken will never be detected as changed.

Comment: For external (non-components), I have passed in what is needed from an outer component when it loads.

Comment: I am not sure if I know what you are referring to in practice. Is it a closure of some sort? I am wondering if in this case, I could dispatch an event on the window object during the interception to signal that the tokens were changed. However, this seems probably like an antipattern and not the `react` way to do it.

Comment: There isn't a really good way of using stuff outside of a component.